# Is there a way of including internationalized strings outside of the build function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

Is there a way to internationalize strings in flutter outside of the `Widget build` function?
Normally, I would use this:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.settings
```

to access internationalized strings I had defined in the `app_{language}.arb` file but this requires the `context` parameter which is not available outside the build function.
I have tried googling the issue but I can't find any solutions. Do the strings have to be defined inside of the build function?

Comment: one way could be to define you AppLocalizations instance as global variable or register it as a singleton (using [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) for example). Then you can refer to it anywhere in the code without the need for context.

But please keep in mind, **this is not recommended**. BuildContext is the recommended way for reason; it'll guarantee instant and reliable rebuild in all widgets needed when app language is switched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a navigator key globally and access its context anywhere across app.

Define this globally in main file.

```
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

pass this navigatorKey in Material App navigator key

```
MaterialApp(
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    ...
),
```

Now you can access context from anywhere in app using

```
BuildContext context = navigatorKey.currentState!.context;
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loremIpsum
```